# Do I have to reconfigure after restarting an LDAP service?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm using two LDAP servers in a mirror mode.(active-active hot standby, openldap 2.4)

As explained in an [LDAP document](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconf2.html), instead of using a config file, I configured dynamically with `ldapadd` and `ldapmodify` commands after starting LDAP services.

When I restart the LDAP daemon, do I have to configure again by running the same `ldapadd` and `ldapmodify` commands?

Or, does it find the previous config database and load it by itself?

Any link or comment appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the "cn=config" database is persistent across restarts; it is stored in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d` (in the form of LDIF files representing each entry).